# how to plot different proportions (different sample sizes/different denominator) in a pie chart

Tags: normalization, proportion, pie-chart

I have 5 samples from Asia, Africa, Europe, Oceania and America of different sample sizes. I am looking for  particular mutations in a gene in these samples and I got the following proportions

```
MUTATION "S"
-----------
Asia    = 58.6% (446/761); 
Africa  = 4.1% (47/1143); 
Europe  = 27.4% (99/361); 
Oceania = 0% (0/15); 
America = 18.8% (13/69);
```

I want to make a pie chart out of this. But as samples are of different sizes it will not sum to 100% to plot a pie chart. Is there a way to normalize this proportions to plot a pie chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, as a matter of arithmetic, just find the total and divide by that to get new proportions and then new percents. But the results would be nonsensical. The proportions are separate, and should not be constrained as if parts of a whole.

A pie chart is inappropriate here: just use a bar chart or a dot chart.

Showing the actual numbers is a really good idea, and might impart suitable caution.